# Not able to find element using aaccessibility id as it contains next line

Tags: java, android, appium, mobile-application

Not able to find element as accessibility id is like exactly below:

Ongoing
Tab 2 of 3

xpath is like exactly below

//android.view.View[@content-desc="Ongoing
Tab 2 of 3"]

how could I mention it in single line?

I need it as "Ongoing Tab 2 of 3" but it contains next line.
Is there any way?

I tried as
WebElement ongoingTab = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc="Ongoing" + "\r\n"+ "Tab 2 of 3"]"));
and
WebElement ongoingTab = driver.findElement(AppiumBy.xpath("//android.view.View[@content-desc="Ongoing\r\n"+ "Tab 2 of 3"]"));
but it didn't work.